# Injection by id in a method of an abstract class using annotations

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know if it's possible to reproduce this xml peace of code using the annotations:

```
<bean id="mobileRedirectController" class="uk.co.web.device.MobileRedirectController">
   <property name="deviceUserAgent" ref="mobileUserAgent" />
</bean>

<util:set id="mobileUserAgent">
  <value>Mobile</value>
  <value>iPhone</value>
  <value>...</value>
</util:set>

<bean id="tabletRedirectController" class="uk.co.web.device.TabletRedirectController">
    <property name="deviceUserAgent" ref="tabletUserAgent" />
</bean>

<util:set id="tabletUserAgent">
  <value>iPad</value>
  <value>...</value>
</util:set>
```

and my classes are like this (just the code related to my question):

```
public class MobileRedirectController extends AbstractRedirectController {
}

public class TabletRedirectController extends AbstractRedirectController {
}

public abstract class AbstractRedirectController {
    protected Set<String> deviceUserAgent = new HashSet<String>();
    public void setDeviceUserAgent(Set<String> deviceUserAgent) {
        this.deviceUserAgent = deviceUserAgent;
    }
}
```

Now if I remove the xml for the beans instantiation, I will have something like this:

```
<util:set id="mobileUserAgent">
  <value>Mobile</value>
  <value>iPhone</value>
  <value>...</value>
</util:set>

<util:set id="tabletUserAgent">
  <value>iPad</value>
  <value>...</value>
</util:set>
```

And the classes:

```
@Controller("mobileRedirectController")
public class MobileRedirectController extends AbstractRedirectController {
}

@Controller("tabletRedirectController")
public class TabletRedirectController extends AbstractRedirectController {
}

public abstract class AbstractRedirectController {
    protected Set<String> deviceUserAgent = new HashSet<String>();
    public void setDeviceUserAgent(Set<String> deviceUserAgent) {
        this.deviceUserAgent = deviceUserAgent;
    }
}
```

And now my question, is there a way to inject my list mobileUserAgent in the related controller mobileRedirectController and tabletUserAgent in tabletRedirectController without move the code from the AbstractRedirectController to MobileRedirectController and TabletRedirectController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the code inside the abstract controller but you'll need to write some extra code to inject the `Set`. In the XML version you explicitly set the property. With annotations you will need to use constructor or setter injection to get a hold of the `Set` you're interested in.

```
@Controller("mobileRedirectController")
public class MobileRedirectController extends AbstractRedirectController {

    @Resource("mobileUserAgent")
    public MobileRedirectController(Set<String> deviceUserAgent) {
        setDeviceUserAgent(deviceUserAgent);
    }
}

@Controller("tabletRedirectController")
public class TabletRedirectController extends AbstractRedirectController {

    @Resource("tabletUserAgent")
    public TabletRedirectController(Set<String> deviceUserAgent) {
        setDeviceUserAgent(deviceUserAgent);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm ok, good idea the constructor injection, and it works with `@Resource("mobileUserAgent")` but not with `@Autowire @Qualifier("mobileUserAgent")`, it seems that we can't inject a set with `@Autowire` do you know why this limitation?

Comment: The IoC container in Spring versions < 4 had no support for identifying injection candidates based on generics. Since `@Autowired` is by-type this is a problem. `@Resource` is better suited for referencing beans by name/id. [For more reference read this ](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)